# How to get the calculated pseudo from jsx in scss styles?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-selectors

Here is my case:
I want to get calculated pseudo props - content from jsx to scss.

```
this.state = { content: 'my after pseudo content' }
```

the content will be changed during the progress.

And here is my render body:

```
return <label className={cls('MyTestComponent')}>my test label</label>
```

And here is my scss file

```
// MyTestComponent.scss
.MyTestComponent { &:after {
   content: ''
}}
```

what I want is to get calculated ':after' content from state to the scss file.

I'm using scss and don't want to import styled-component or other third party package.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance for anyone who can solve this problem:)

Comment: Have tried add props style={'&::after'L {content: this.state.content}} to the <label>, but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) in combination with css [attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr), like so:

```
return <label 
  className={cls('MyTestComponent')} 
  data-content={this.state.content}
>
    my test label
</label>
```

```scss
.MyTestComponent { &:after {
   content: attr(data-content);
}}
```